# Can't build opencv 3.2.0 with opencv_contrib 3.2.0

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm trying to build opencv and opencv_contrib module but i'm getting following while building with cmake-gui :

```
Detected version of GNU GCC: 54 (504)
Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.8", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.8") 
Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
  No package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
  No package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
  No package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
  No package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
  No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
  No package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
  No package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
  No package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
  No package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' found
Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
  No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' found
Looking for linux/videodev.h
Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
Looking for linux/videodev2.h
Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
Looking for sys/videoio.h
Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
Checking for module 'libavresample'
  No package 'libavresample' found
Checking for module 'libgphoto2'
  No package 'libgphoto2' found
found IPP (ICV version): 9.0.1 [9.0.1]
at: /opencv-master/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could NOT find Atlas (missing:  Atlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
A library with BLAS API found.
A library with LAPACK API found.
Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
Caffe:   NO
Protobuf:   NO
Glog:   NO
The protocol buffer compiler is found (/usr/bin/protoc)
CMake Error at /opencv_contrib-master/modules/dnn/cmake/OpenCVFindLibProtobuf.cmake:17 (PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP):
  Unknown CMake command "PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opencv_contrib-master/modules/dnn/CMakeLists.txt:5 (include)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/opencv-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/opencv-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

***Error box : Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid***

Please look into it.

Comment: What is your platform ?

Comment: I'm using Linuxmint 18.1 , it worked when I unchecked protobuf and opencv_dnn in cmake-gui and then configured it again.

Answer (score 1):

**You must have matching versions of the opencv_contrib and the opencv itself.**

Another fellow had a similar issue that is caused by the same thing. You can see my answer on the stack overflow [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800482/unable-to-add-extra-module-opencv-contrib-to-opencv/43816099?noredirect=1#comment74722081_43816099)