# unable to add extra module (opencv_contrib) to opencv

Tags: opencv

i am trying to install opencv_config modules in my existing opencv am i am getting errors. Please help on how can i rectify. [first screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsCzj.png)

[second screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wlrs.png)

Comment: I see you are using CMake to compile. Can you share that?

Comment: cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<opencv_contrib>/modules <opencv_source_directory>

Comment: above is the command and i am using instruction from this link https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/rqt3u and http://imgur.com/a/bIwll are my cmake options

Comment: I think you'll have to manually install those missing dependencies and then run cmake again.

Comment: and how should i manually install opencv_contrib ??? it doesnt contain cmakelist

Comment: I meant pre-installing the gstreamer and other depency errors you might have and then running cmake again to see if it solves it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that you must have ***matching versions*** of both the OpenCV and the opencv_contrib. So, for version **3.2.0** you should have **opencv_contrib-3.2.0**. To get the matching versions, do the following.

Download the OpenCV 3.2.0 from its [Github Releases tab](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases)

Download the opencv_contrib-3.2.0 from its [Github Releases tab](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/releases)

Now that you have both versions matching, you are good to go and follow the OpenCV installation tutorial.

Comment: Great! I am glad that I could help :)
Since it did work, please mark my answer as correct so that others can see it too. Have a great day!